# Can I somehow merge these classes such that I don't have to write this again and again and my python code doesn't get redundant

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dry

```
import datetime

# I AM CREATING A BIKE RENTAL SYSTEM USING OOP IN PYTHON AND SOMEHOW I SEE MYSELF REPEATING SAME CONTENTS IN METHODS, CAN I SOMEHOW WRITE THIS IN BETTER FORMAT WHICH ISNT REDUNDANT? (I AM NEW TO OOP)

class BikeRental:

    def __init__(self, stock=0):
        #creating instances of bike rental shop
        self.stock = stock

    def displayStock(self):
        #displaying currently available bikes to rent
        print(f'We currently have {self.stock} bikes available for rent')
        return self.stock

    def BikeOnHourly(self, input):
        #rents bike on hourly basis
        if input < 0:
            print('Number of bikes should be positive!')
            return None

        elif input > self.stock:
            print(f'Sorry we have {self.stock} bikes available right now!')
            return None

        else:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(f'you have rented {input} bike/bikes on hourly basis today'
                  f'at {now.hour} on {now.date()}')
            print('you will be charged 5$ per bike per hour.')
            print('Have a great and healthy day!')

            self.stock -= input
            return now

    def BikeOnDailyBasis(self, n):

        if n< 0:
            print('Number of bikes should be positive!')
            return None
        elif n >self.stock:
            print(f'Sorry we have {self.stock} bikes available right now!')
        else:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(f'you have rented {n} bike/bikes on hourly basis today'
                  f'at {now.hour} on {now.date()}')
            print('you will be charged 5$ per bike per hour.')
            print('Have a great and healthy day!')

            self.stock -= n
            return now
```

Comment: There's only one class in the question. What classes do you want to combine?

Comment: What's the difference between `BikeOnDailyBasis` and `BikeOnHourly`? Why are they different functions?

Comment: Write one function that contains all the common code, and call it from both `BikeOnDailyBasis` and `BikeOnHourly`.

Comment: thanks barmar, I got the idea of that, can i use class methods for the same purpose? will it work the same way?

Comment: Why does `BikeOnDailyBasis` print "you have rented {n} bike/bikes on **hourly** basis today"? Shouldn't that message say "daily"? And where does it actually record that the rentals are daily rather than hourly?

Comment: yeah its on daily basis now, i was working on the code simultaneously so.. yeah updated that, For that record i have created a customer class and took rental_time from the user and saved it in customer instance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are asking about repeating the function, not the class. If so, something like this might be helpful, with the idea being to have different functions call the one BikeOnBasis function with a varying parameter basis. Also see [polymorphism](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/polymorphism) for info on doing this type of thing in more structured ways.

```py
import datetime

# I AM CREATING A BIKE RENTAL SYSTEM USING OOP IN PYTHON AND SOMEHOW I SEE MYSELF REPEATING SAME CONTENTS IN METHODS, CAN I SOMEHOW WRITE THIS IN BETTER FORMAT WHICH ISNT REDUNDANT? (I AM NEW TO OOP)

class BikeRental:

    def __init__(self, stock=0):
        #creating instances of bike rental shop
        self.stock = stock

    def displayStock(self):
        #displaying currently available bikes to rent
        print(f'We currently have {self.stock} bikes available for rent')
        return self.stock

    def BikeOnHourly(self, n):
        self.BikeOnBasis(n, 'hourly')

    def BikeOnDailyBasis(self, n):
        self.BikeOnBasis(n, 'daily')

    def BikeOnBasis(self, n, basis):
        if n< 0:
            print('Number of bikes should be positive!')
            return None
        elif n > self.stock:
            print(f'Sorry we have {self.stock} bikes available right now!')
        else:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            print(f'you have rented {n} bike/bikes on {basis} basis today'
                  f'at {now.hour} on {now.date()}')
            print('you will be charged 5$ per bike per hour.')
            print('Have a great and healthy day!')

            self.stock -= n
            return now
```

Comment: can I create a class method for repeating stuff and add it to the other classes? will it work the same way ?

Comment: btw this is completely helpful and sure I will checkout polymorphism, thx for the help